# BIRT report, how to bind currency property on a dataset to the number formatting of a label

Tags: binding, report, currency, birt, number-formatting

I am creating a bill in BIRT. I have created the template already, and have played around with having a column and then a heading that would indicate the currency.

However I would now like to have the currency as part of the row formatting, in other words I would like it to look like this:

$ 120,000.00

The currency ($) is read from the database, and I have it as part of a dataset that can be used by the parameter. Only problem is - I do not know if this parameter can somehow be bound to the formatting of the label?

Kind Regards,
Harriet

Answer (score 1):

This is quite straight to do this by building a dynamic number format. In Eclipse Designer, click your data element containing the currency number to be formatted -> Script tab -> onCreate

For example, enter this script (assuming the dataset column containing the currency is named "currency"):

```
this.getStyle().numberFormat=row["currency"]+" ###,##0.00 ";
```